# How to resolve error rendering view nodejs mongoose pug

Tags: javascript, mongoose, async-await, pug

I'm following the library website project on MDN but for some reason the book_list view gives an error on line 11. I have exactly copied the code from MDN as in the link below. If I comment line 11 the view renders as below but the author names do not appear which is the desired result as you will see in the MDN link [get a list of all Book objects in the database](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Displaying_data/Book_list_page):

Here is the github link: https://github.com/mdn/express-locallibrary-tutorial

I get the error:
/Projects/API/express-locallibrary-tutorial/views/book_list.pug:11 9| li 10| a(href=book.url) #{book.title} > 11| | (#{book.author.name}) 12| 13| else 14| li There are no books. Assignment to constant variable.

[image]

Comment: Please include a minimal representation of your code as formatted text within the body of your question instead of linking out to an external repo.

Comment: Please find below the relevant code:

Comment: There is no code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing my code with MDN again, I noticed in my code I had declared the variable fullname in the author model using const which was causing the issue. Using let or var to declare the variable fixed the issue.

Have to revisit on var, let and const